# ASP.NET Core Web API returns incomplete JSON data when I use 'include' in my query

Tags: c#, json, api, asp.net-core-mvc

I use ASP.NET Core Web API 2.2 for retrieving data from a database.

My query is like this

```
 public IEnumerable<BaseCompany> GetAllActive()
 {
     return  _context.BaseCompanies.Where(x => x.Active).ToList();
 }
```

it return company data that save in my database but i Have many relation that I need get their data in my api like this

```
 public IEnumerable<BaseCompany> GetAllActive()
    {
        return  _context.BaseCompanies.Where(x => x.Active)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCity)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCompanyGroupFour)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCompanyGroupOne)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCompanyGroupThree)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCompanyGroupTwo)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCompanyTitle)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCompanyType)
            .Include(b => b.BaseCountry)
            .Include(b => b.BaseProvince).ToList();
    }
```

Ok, when I want to get data from second query my data that return from database are incomplete,

More description: first I use SQLite, I think SQLite doesn't support this relation, change it to Postgresql but return the same.

Also, I check another database that have relation with main table `BaseCompany` => all columns is fill with correct data, what is my mistake?

**UPDATE**: my json returned is like this when use second query without `{` and `]`:

```
{"page":{"total":1,"data":[{"id":1,"code":"1","baseCompanyTitle":null,"baseCompanyTitleId":1,"name":"Name Company","phone1":"03444344616","phone2":null,"fax":null,"activityName":"TRead","postalCode":"1","postalBox":"1","efectiveDate":"2019-08-12T00:00:00","baseCountry":null,"baseCountryId":1,"baseProvince":null,"baseProvinceId":1,"baseCity":{"id":1,"createDate":"2019-08-12T00:00:00","modifyDate":"2019-08-12T00:00:00","active":true,"baseLanguageId":1,"baseLanguage":null,"name":"seattle","description":"...","baseCountry":null,"baseCountryId":1,"baseProvince":null,"baseProvinceId":1,"baseCompanies":[
```

but without `.include(...)`, return complete like this

```
[{"id":3,"code":"1","baseCompanyTitle":null,"baseCompanyTitleId":1,"name":"Name Company","phone1":"1","phone2":"1","fax":"1","activityName":"1","postalCode":"76","postalBox":"75","efectiveDate":"2019-08-13T00:00:00","baseCountry":null,"baseCountryId":1,"baseProvince":null,"baseProvinceId":1,"baseCity":null,"baseCityId":1,"address":"1111","email":"@","createDate":"2019-08-13T00:00:00","modifyDate":"2019-08-13T00:00:00","active":true,"baseCompanyType":null,"baseCompanyTypeId":1,"description":"1","importantNote":"no import note","baseCompanyGroupOne":null,"baseCompanyGroupOneId":1,"baseCompanyGroupSubOne":null,"basCompanyGroupSubOneId":1,"baseCompanyGroupTwo":null,"baseCompanyGroupTwoId":1,"baseCompanyGroupThree":null,"baseCompanyGroupThreeId":1,"baseCompanyGroupFour":null,"baseCompanyGroupFourId":1}]},"totalPage":1.0}
```

After get an answer to disable LazyLoading and search can't fine a way to do that in ef core 2.2 alternative I use `AsNoTracking()` in my query but still have the same result

**Update #2**: as the return value in complete Json, without any data from related table, I will get all data but if I use ".INCLUDE()" in my query, for ex:include(x=>x.BaseCountries), data will return to country until create a loop to the "basecompany" Table

Comment: please update you question with what are missing. and example of the result json.

Comment: i updated and set original return value by correct return and incomplete return

Comment: what are you using to serialize the object to JSON? None of those are valid JSON. Try use Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject() method and update the question with the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I resolve by add this code to startup.cs

```
 services.AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(
        options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore)
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using EF 6, you need to disable lazy load before commit your query:

```
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
```

[EF 6 doc: lazyloadingenabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.lazyloadingenabled?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

For EF Core (Net Core 2.1) you should use this [ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.changetracker.lazyloadingenabled?view=efcore-2.1)

Comment: this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; is for ef 6 how can i do for EfCore 2.2

Comment: @sunny, please see the last link i added yesterday related to EF Core.